# Not able to get output

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I am new to hybrid app development using Cordova with Onsen .

My project was working fine but I changed some script links but now I am not able to see the output.

I just asked a question on SO  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36695163/unable-to-run-angular-js-code-with-onsen-cordova/36743468#36743468) and till then everything was correct.

I have shared the project folder on   [FileDropper](http://www.filedropper.com/onsenui)

**Below is the output :**

**index.html**

[image]

**p2.html**

[image]

*I have linked p2.html in index.html but its not displaying when I open index.html*

*Thanks in Advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your project - it looks like you upgraded to Onsen 2. In that case in order to use Onsen UI with Angular you need to include `angular-onsenui`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-onsenui.min.js"></script>
```

And also later you need to call `ons.bootstrap()`. You can do that either in the empty `script` which you have right before the body, or just add it inside your `js/index.js` file.

I made these 2 changes and everything was working. :)

Comment: @llia Yatchev every time I press the back button its ending the app can you tell me why its happening .It was working previously

Comment: @AshishShukla: About the removed comment - it seems like you are missing the `row` and `col` classes. Adding them will fix it. About the backbutton there are a couple of potential reasons. First one being if cordova wasn't loaded properly. The other thing is - you can set it with onsen. Here are the [__docs__](https://onsen.io/2/reference/ons.html#methods-summary). I guess it just depends on what you want to do when you click the backbutton. Maybe before there was some default behaviour which was changed.

Comment: Also on a side note - if you have a page which you're expecting to show inside an onsen component with the `page` attribute or something similar then you don't actually need all the tags like `html`, `body`, `head` - you can just provide the content which you want, since it's already inside another page, so you don't need to nest those tags. :)

Comment: Great  I will follow that.